# How to force opening of a separate window in an Unix script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a small UNIX script that I want to open via double commander ( https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/ ):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo sshfs pi@192.168.178.23:/ ~/mount-pi/data -o reconnect -o allow_other
```

This script mounts a remote file system in a dedicated directory of my local machine.

When this script gets executed from a bash (and not from double commander), I get asked  for the sudo passwords of both machines.

The graphical user interface of double commander allows me to execute the script via a double click, but the script seems to fail silently as no passwords are supplied.

How do I have to modify this script that it gets executed in another bash when clicking on it so that I can supply both passwords in that bash?

**Remark:**

I use Ubuntu / Compiz / Unity, and I need this in a graphical environment.

Comment: If you want to get a terminal window in a graphical environment you have to run a terminal application. Try something like `xterm -e 'sudo sshfs pi@192.168.178.23:/ ~/mount-pi/data -o reconnect -o allow_other'`. This will not work if you are not in a graphical environment, e.g. if you use a (virtual) console.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @glennjackman: I use Ubuntu / Compiz / Unity.

Comment: @Bodo: this solves my question. Thanks. I would accept it as an answer, if you want to post it as an answer accordingly.

Comment: @TomRoden Please add all requested information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a terminal window in a graphical environment you have to run a terminal application.

Try something like

```
xterm -e 'sudo sshfs pi@192.168.178.23:/ ~/mount-pi/data -o reconnect -o allow_other'
```

There are other terminal applications. Choose the one you like or that fits your requirements.

Of course this will not work if you are **not** in a graphical environment, e.g. if you use a (virtual) console.